# Using Java reserved variables as names

Tags: java, variables, names

Technically using variable names such as int, flow, double, class, etc.. can work but it isn't recommended from what I know.

Are there any cases where it would be fine to use these reserved names?

Comment: always seek clarity and elegance in one's code, so why introduce anything against that. reserved keywords should remain reserved unless you have a great reason to not do so. If you don't, don't seek them.

Comment: Basically what Shawn said. And this: "Always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live."

Comment: It would be fine to use them as Strings such as in a `HashMap<String, OtherType>`, but regarding whether it's fine to use as variable names, it doesn't matter - you can't as the compiler won't let you.

Comment: Never heard of "flow", but the others can never be Java variable names.

Comment: @DavidWallace "flow" = float :D

Comment: May I also suggest not to talk about this idea when you go to a job interview

Comment: @R4J: Guess that explains the bricks through my windows at night and the inverted pentagram/demonic images graffiti on my door and home's exterior that have been a constant source of concern for me since that last big project I was on.  I was wondering about it, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question could not be put any simpler:

**Answer:** No, there is no way. Hence the label 'reserved'.